Error response from daemon: Get "https://harbor-xxxx": dial tcp: lookup harbor-labnum.aphp.fr on xx.XXX.XX:53: no such host
i have installed harbor registring with docker compose and it works as expected.
but when i rtry to do docker login https://harbor-domain-name it gives me this error :
Error response from daemon: Get "https://harbor-domain-name/v2/": dial tcp: lookup harbor-domain-name on xx.XX.XX:53: no such host

could you help please ?
